# Valid Parens method - Java

Tags: java

Can anyone suggest the best optimized way to solve this coding puzzle?
I used a bunch of if statements and was told that just increased cyclomatic complexity. Is the solution a regex or a data structure (such as a stack)? Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

```
/**
 * Write a function that will take a string as input and output
 * a boolean (true or false) that describes if the string has valid parens.
 *
 * Use Cases:
 *
 * "" -> false
 *
 * null -> false
 *
 * "()" -> true
 *
 * ")" -> false
 *
 * "(" -> false
 *
 * "(())" -> true
 *
 * "())(" -> false
 *
 * "()))" -> false
 *
 * ")(" -> false 
 *
 * "()()" -> true
 */
public boolean validParen(String input) {
    // implementation? 
}
```

Comment: Try writing a function that performs next operation: `(state, symbol) -> state`, where `state` contains information about already processed `input` (at least its correctness), and `symbol` is the next character of the `input`.

Comment: What should it return if a non-parens character is found?

Comment: I'd start with looking at each character, counting the number of left **(** and right **)** (separately) (obviously going from start of the string to the end). If result is 0, false. If result is the same not false. However, if the number of rights is ever greater than the lefts then immediately false. Haven't fully checked the validity but it's a start. This would utilise a loop.

Answer (score 2):

To simply check if the brackets are valid (in pairs), you don't really need any data structure. Just increment a counter variable when you encounter a ( and decrement it when its pair is found ). At the end the counter should = 0 if the ( and ) are balanced:

```
static boolean check(String toCheck) {
    if (toCheck == null || toCheck.equals(""))
        return false;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < toCheck.length(); i++) {
        char c = toCheck.charAt(i);
        if (c == '(') {
            count++;
        } else if (c == ')') {
            if (count == 0)
                return false;
            count--;
        }
    }
    return count == 0;
}
```

Comment: This fails for the following values: `null`, `""`, `")("`, etc. Also, why not use a `for` loop?

Comment: @Andreas obviously I didn't consider all the use cases, edited according to your suggestion, thanks for correcting.

Comment: `toCheck.equals("")` is better written as `toCheck.isEmpty()`.

Comment: Actually, "".equals(toCheck) is better than toCheck.equals("") or toCheck.isEmpty()

Answer (score 1):

You just need a counter.

If input is null or empty string, return false.

Then iterate the characters of the string, and increment the counter when you see a `(`, and decrement the counter when you see a `)`.

If you see a `)` and the counter is zero, return false.
If the counter is not zero at the end, return false.
Otherwise return true.